# Put any special character in document as is

Tags: verbatim

I'm having problem in representing special characters in a PDF document as they are, without being interpreted by latex.

To not mistakenly take my question as a duplicate, let me explain what's my intent and how far I have gone with it.

I'm trying to make a PDF document containing pair of username and passphrasees each in one line, and having hyphen character filled between each pair. So far, I made this possible by following lines of code:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\dashfill}{
    \leavevmode\xleaders\hbox{-}\hfill\kern0pt
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
1. cname@domain.tld \dashfill passphrase
\end{document}
```

Notice the new command `\dashfill` I found in other threads. This will cause trouble as I'm explaining further.

First problem raised when I realized passphrases contain special characters which will be interpreted by latex, for example:

```tex
\begin{document}
1. cname@domain.tld \dashfill not all $characters$ are accepted
\end{document}
```

Which results this output:

[image]

Of course, this is not acceptable as the dollar sign `$` character gets missed, and this is only one character, there can be many more special characters in passphrases and as they are dynamically generated, I cannot tell which characters need to be escaped, if they can be.

I searched and realized that there is a `\verbatim` block, but it's not an answer because `\dashfill` command or any other commands don't work within that block (please tell me otherwise):

```tex
\begin{verbatim}
1. cname@domain.tld \dashfill not all $characters$ are accepted
\end{verbatim}
```

[image]

The desire output has the form of:

```
01. cname@domain.tld ---- P@$$phr@$e
```

Having that, username and passphrase parts should be printed as is on document, and the `\dashfill` command between them should be interpreted.

I searched for **inline verbatim** and similar, I found this solution:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\dashfill}{
    \leavevmode\xleaders\hbox{-}\hfill\kern0pt
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\expandafter\string\csname 01. cname@domain.tld \endcsname
\dashfill
\expandafter\string\csname passphrase \endcsname\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Though it seems like improvement, still there are major problems with it:

1. There are still characters not being printed like underscore `_`, as the word `With` was surrounded by it.
2. There's a strange quote character before **username** and **passphrase** section.

I'm lost with the complexity of LaTeX!
But there should be a way to see username and passphrases as desired. Is it?

Comment: Try \verb|whatever| . The | is chosen arbitrarily. It can be anything that‘s not in the enclosed string. Does it change anything?

Comment: @MS-SPO Tried that, it works except that another problem raises. What if there's a | or in other case "the delimiter" in the passphrase? I'm looking if it's possible to have multi-character delimiters. Or if I'm having it all wrong thinking of open-close characters as delimiters. I'll work around it, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absorb the passphrase verbatim:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\dashfill}{% <--- don't forget
  \leavevmode\xleaders\hbox{-}\hfill\kern0pt
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\passphrase}{mv}{%
  \texttt{#1}~\dashfill~\texttt{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item\passphrase{cname@domain.tld}{passphrase}

\item\passphrase{cname@domain.tld}{&6^00-\\uu%}

\item\passphrase{cname@domain.tld}|&{6^00-\\uu%|

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

You can see that you can even have unmatched braces in the passphrase, so long as you delimit it with a character that's not in it (in this case `|`).

[image]

If you're running a LaTeX version prior to October 2021, you may need to add `\usepackage{xparse}`.

Comment: Heartiest congrats for `1 million` points, hope you are the first one, achieved this...

Comment: Your answer targeted my question so accurately it should be printed and hanged on my wall! Thanks. Happy crossing over 1M points by the way.